# Computing Ceil of Log2 in Rust

Tags: rust

I want to calculate the following in Rust:

Python Equivalent:

```py
math.ceil(math.log(b+1, 2))
```

[ceil(log_2 n+1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zomj.png)

I have tried:

```rust
a+1.log2() 
(a+1).log2()
```

but I get the error `use of unstable library feature 'int_log'`. I don't want to use an unstable library feature. What is the easiest way to calculate log2, without any external crates if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rust is very particular about the difference between ints and floats. You can't just type a integer and expect it to be auto-casted automatically. Always add a `.` at the end for a float.

Seems like you attempted to call the function on a integer. Try this:

Try this:

```rs
(1.).log2().ceil()
```

or

```rs
(a as f32 + 1.).log2().ceil()
```

If you want the end result as a integer you can use `as i32` at the end. If you want double precision floats replace `f32` with `f64`.

Reference:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.ceil

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.log2

Comment: I think `f32::from`/`f32::try_from` are preferable as they indicate whether or not the conversion is guaranteed to succeed. On the other hand, `as` always appears to succeed, but may not (for instance if `a` is a `u64`). I get the impression that if they could do it over, `as` would only apply to raw pointers and a handful of other types, but not the integer primitives.

Comment: @BallpointBen For raw pointers almost never use `as` (use `cast::<T>()`), and soon it will be _never_ use `as` (use the Pointee API instead). For integers it is better to use `from()`/`try_from()`, but the problem is that there is no truncating alternative. But yes, there is demand to deprecate `as`.

Answer (score 12):

If this is time-critical then you can use knowledge of the datatypes to make things fast.

If the input is a positive integer (let's say a `u64`), then `log2(x)` is *almost* the index of the last non-1 bit, which you can determine using `u64::leading_zeros`. In fact `log2(x+1)` is exactly the index of the last non-1 bit of x. This gives: [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8cef5848a2a99730015dde5adacb48ae)

```
pub fn main() {
    for a in 0..10u64 {
        let v = (a as f32 + 1.).log2().ceil();
        let w = u64::BITS - a.leading_zeros();
        println!("{} {} {}", a, v, w);
    }
}
```

outputs

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 2 2
4 3 3
5 3 3
6 3 3
7 3 3
8 4 4
9 4 4
```

A little more care is needed to handle the sign-bit for signed numbers like `i64`.

If your number is a floating-point value, there are still some tricks you can play to make things fast, especially if you are willing not to handle NaN, Inf and denormalised numbers.

In particular, for f64 the bit pattern for "normal" numbers is
52 bits of "fraction", 11 bits of mantissa and 1 sign bit. Calling the 11 bits of mantissa `e` the value of the float is `(sign)*(1+fraction/2^52)*2^(e-1023)`

So `log2(x) = log2(1+fraction/2^52) + (e-1023)`.

The `e-1023` part is an integer, the rest as `0<=log2(1+fraction/2^52)<1`, with zero when `fraction==0`. So `ceil(log2(x)) = if fraction==0 {e-1023} else {e-1022}`.

This gives us [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e7c5de2433bbffa9591cfdf646632659):

```
pub fn main() {
    for a in -20..20i64 {
        let f = (a as f64)/4.0 + 1.0;
        let v = f.log2().ceil();
        let b: u64 = f.to_bits();
        let s = (b >> 63) & 1;
        let e = (b >> 52) & ((1<<11)-1);
        let frac = b & ((1<<52) -1);
        let z = if frac==0 { e as i64 - 1023 } else { e as i64 -1022 };
        println!("{:0.2} {:064b} : {:01b} {:011b} {:052b} {} {}", f, b, s, e, frac, z, v);
    }
}
```

which outputs (after trimming out the bit representations)

```
...
-0.75 ... -2 -2
-0.50 ... -1 -1
-0.25 ... 0 -0
 0.00 ... 0 0
 0.25 ... 1 1
 0.50 ... 1 1
 0.75 ... 1 1
 1.00 ... 1 1
 1.25 ... 2 2
 1.50 ... 2 2
 1.75 ... 2 2
 2.00 ... 2 2
...
```

Again, this only holds when 1+a is a normal number. You'll need to add conditionals to handle those if you need to. (And you should unless you're sure you don't need to).

Similar tricks can be used for u32 and f32 types.

Comment: This answer deserve more likes

Answer (score 1):

try these out! since 1.67.0

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.ilog2
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_ilog2

```rust
(a as i32 + 1).ilog2()
```